# What is meant by "Nothing" in Physics/Quantum Physics?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, vacuum, virtual-particles

I am not a phycisist, so please forgive my ignorance. This is related to my [posts](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/30894/) and [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/30965/).
I am trying to understand what is meant by the term *"Nothing"* in physics or Quantum Field Theory (QFT) since it seems to me that this term is not used in the way we understand it in everyday language.
So QFT seems to suggest (in a nutshell) that "things pop out of **nothing**".
But from [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_fluctuation) I see the following quote:

> "According to quantum theory, the vacuum contains neither matter nor
>   energy, but it does contain fluctuations, transitions between
>   something and nothing in which potential existence can be transformed
>   into real existence by the addition of energy.(Energy and matter are
>   equivalent, since all matter ultimately consists of packets of
>   energy.) Thus, the vacuum's totally empty space is actually a seething
>   turmoil of creation and annihilation, which to the ordinary world
>   appears calm because the scale of fluctuations in the vacuum is tiny
>   and the fluctuations tend to cancel each other out.

So what is "Nothing" in QFT? If this quote is correct, I can interpret it only as follows:
The "Nothing" is not in the way used in everyday speech but is *composed* of "transitions" i.e. something that is "about to become"
Is this correct? If yes, why is this defined as "Nothing"? Something that is "about to become" is not nothing but there is something prerequisite.
In very lame terms: Einstein was born a non-physicist but became a physicist, so if this is a correct analogy, then there

1. ***there is something*** underlying that was non-something that became
   something
2. A non-something came into something because something else (not
   nothing) *permitted it to become*. E.g. Einstein's talent (or
   Mozart's) would have been lost had he been born in Africa or in a
   country with no educational facilities. So he would not become a physicist (but the required talent would be present but not come into reality)

Could someone please help me understand this (perhaps trivial to you) concept?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/34049/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In Physics "nothing" is generally taken to be the lowest energy state of a theory. We wouldn't normally use the word "nothing" but instead describe the lowest energy state as the "vacuum". I can't think of an intuitive way to describe the QM vacuum because all the obvious analogies have "something" instead of nothing "nothing", so I'll do my best but you may still find the idea hard to grasp. That's not just you - everybody finds it hard to grasp.

Start with the classical description of an electric field ([Maxwell's equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%27s_equations)). It's not too hard to image an electric field as a field filling space. You can even feel the field: for example if you put your hand near an old style TV screen you can feel the static electricity. You can imagine turning down the electric field until it disappears completely, in which case you are left with the vacuum i.e. nothing.

Now imagine the same field, but this time we're using the quantum description of the field ([Quantum Electrodynamics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_Electrodynamics) instead of Maxell's equations). At the classical level the field is approximately the same as the description Maxwell's equations give, but now we have fluctuations in the field due to the energy-time uncertainty principle. Just as before, imagine turning down the electric field until it disappears. Unlike the classical description, the (average) electric field may disappear but the fluctuations do not. This means the quantum vacuum is different from the classical vacuum because it contains the fluctuations even after you've turned the field down to zero.

The key point is that when I say "turn the field down" I mean reduce the energy to the lowest it will go i.e. you can't make the energy of the electric field any lower. By definition this is what we call the "vacuum" even though it isn't empty (i.e. it contains the fluctuations). It isn't possible to make the vacuum any emptier because the fluctuations are always present and you can't remove them.

Comment: So a first conclusion I make from a first reading of your answer (thank you for your help) is that what a physicist means when says Nothing does not have an exact equivalent with the term Nothing that we ordinary people use in our everyday speech.Did I get this part?

Comment: Well, physicists use the word "vacuum" when they specifically mean a quantum field theory ground state. The word "nothing" doesn't have a specific meaning in physics. However you are basically correct in that for most people "vacuum" and "nothing" are the same thing, while for physicists "vacuum" and "nothing" mean different things.

Comment: A second point is that from `"nothing" is generally taken to be the lowest energy state of a theory` 1) Each "theory" has a different notion of "nothing" 2) `lowest energy state` is not the same as `no energy state`. Are these (2) also correct?

Comment: Have a look at my updated answer to http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/30965 as I think it addresses some of your concerns.

Comment: I know this is the standard language but is "fluctuations" really an appropriate word? I mean the vacuum state would be an eigenstate of the Hamiltonian (and thus, would be a stationary state). I never understood why we use the word "fluctuations".

Comment: @FeynmansOutforGrumpyCat agreed, but I'm trying to give a simple explanation. See [Are vacuum fluctuations really happening all the time?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/146003/are-vacuum-fluctuations-really-happening-all-the-time) for my non-simplified explanation.

Answer (score 4):

At an even more abstract level (and inspired by the John Rennie's TV analogy): you seem to think of "Nothing" as the equivalent of a black TV screen. In modern physics, "Nothing" is similar to the [noise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aAnalog_TV_noise.ogv) between TV channels.

Answer (score 2):

If we take "nothing" to be the same as "zero", "something" to be the same as "not-zero", the vacuum state is both "nothing" and "something".

The "nothing" part of the vacuum state as a theoretical object is that the *average* value of a series of measurements of the field will be zero. The "something" part of the vacuum state is that the value of any *single* measurement will in general not be zero. When we can't predict single measurement results and how they will vary over time, we often find that we *can* predict average values and how the average values will vary over time.

There will most likely be technical aspects to any Physicist's answer here. In the above, "measurements of the field" must be understood to have quite theoretical connotations. John Rennie has labored heroically, but ultimately you have to work at being an intimate friend of the Math and its relationship to experiment.

You seem to be trying to make "nothing" be something vaguely different from any mathematical idea.

Comment: `a theoretical object is that the average value of a series of measurements of the field will be zero` doesn't this depend on the scale?Perhaps it is because my lack of background but it seems to me that the term Nothing is a misnomer. It is actual a "handy" name for something so small that is negligible.But in reality there is "something"

Comment: I think no. The average value predicted by the theory for measurements of the field in the vacuum state is zero. *Not* so small as to be negligible. The measurements we really record in lab books and in computer memory are never measurements of the vacuum state, however, because there's always a nontrivial environment, always thermal fluctuations, etc., all of which has to be modeled. The vacuum is the maximally symmetric starting point for an idealized theoretical model, just as the zero-valued classical field is the starting point for modeling classical systems.

Answer (score 2):

Simple answer to the simple question Yes this is definately a mis-nomer.

Nothing has come to mean in physics the base state. I will try not to use the word "nothing" in my description.

Soft Answer:

In the simplest terms if I start with zero apples and add one apple then eat that apple before you see it(and continuously add and subtract just as fast as they are added) that is what the word is being used for there was something but when you checked you got the answer of zero whichh is just what I started with(the base state) it is just a almost accurate description of a [QED Vacuum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QED_vacuum)

The necessary physics part is:
    “The quantum theory asserts that a vacuum, even the most perfect vacuum devoid of any matter, is not really empty. Rather the quantum vacuum can be depicted as a sea of continuously appearing and disappearing [pairs of] particles that manifest themselves in the apparent jostling of particles that is quite distinct from their thermal motions. These particles are ‘virtual’, as opposed to real, particles. ...At any given instant, the vacuum is full of such virtual pairs, which leave their signature behind, by affecting the energy levels of atoms.”

Comment: Interesting analogy.But where do this apple you add and eat come from?

Comment: If myself or anyone on this site knew that answer to that question, it would be all over the news.

Comment: Fair enough.But I guess what you are saying here is that what the observation is, is that in time X there was nothing there and time X+δτ there is an apple.What I don't get is why it is believed that the apple appeared suddenly (and lost afterwards) and not that it was always there, but we couldn't detect it? Seems more reasonable to me that supporting that nothing is the "birth" of something.Does this make sense to you?I don't have your background and perhaps this seems to simplistic/dumb for you

Comment: For the most part because we only detect(at this time) the effect of this vaccum as it relates to the energy of atoms.

Comment: My background involves 1 week in a high school history class describing Issac newton sitting under a tree. So there is no too simplistic in my view. Lol but thank you for makeing me feel smart.

Comment: my analogy is slightly askew not one apple but a pair of apples that part and then recombine and in that recombining effect the energy of atoms.

Comment: Again the birth of existence and what caused this birth is another one of those nobody has exactly figured it out yet.

Comment: The birth of particle and antiparticle in vacuum  is due to borrowing energy from underlying field (maybe space). So they borrow energy and come in existence  and then collapse together  and give energy back to that underlying field. Also I'm not a phycisist.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not  a physicist  but based on studies I did : all types of elementary particles and forcrs also have  fields in the whole universe. and fields always are there so even if we don't see any particle in a place it does't mean that there is "nothing" in that place because fields are always there. based on the uncertainty principle Since we can't  accurately calculate the energy of a specific  system in a specified time , the conclusion is that the energy of system can not be absolutely zero.so changes happens in the fields even in places we think that is empty. in this case virtual particles and  virtual antiparticles borrow energy from system to come in existence  and then after a short time they collide togheter and give back this energy to system. So actually "nothing" does not exist. Forgive me for my poor english.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a semantic issue in the way physics represents energy states, that comes from uncertainty and our common understanding of the number zero.

For conceptual purposes, it would be better semantics to use the term "potential," and define "nothing" strictly as "absolute non-potential."

Anything more, including the vacuum at its lowest energy-state, would definitely still be "something."

Even at the lowest-possible energy state, because of uncertainty (which I'd even go as far as claiming is a physical behavior of spacetime itself),

the potential exists in, as, and of the vacuum, and that potential must be called "real."

The potential is, and that is something.

"Absolute non-potential" "Nothing," is a human concept that has no place in physics and cannot be part of nature, bc the set of no possibilities whatsoever necessarily precludes the possibility even for itself.

It's intrinsically a double-negative, whose very definition means "that which is not."

It can only exist as an idea, but still helpful to use for describing our experience.

In physics & nature, there's never nothing nowhere. Great question!