# What causes a single photon to divert its trajectory?

Tags: general-relativity, optics, particle-physics, gravity, visible-light

If a single photon passes close enough to a star, the gravity will diverts its trajectory. What causes a photon to divert its trajectory as it passes a sharp edge or the boundary of two mediums?

Comment: Passing near a star produces gravity lensing, not diffraction. Passing the boundary between two mediums produces refraction, not diffraction.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refractive_index#Microscopic_explanation

Comment: This is an impressive mix of disparate concepts, (i) the curved null geodesics that light follows in GR, (ii) *refraction* at the boundary between different media, and (iii) diffraction, which happens when light encounters a finite aperture. None of those concepts has anything to do with the others.

Comment: @puppetsock My question says nothing about re-fraction or diffraction. I am only asking how the two are different. Not even sure why that question would be down voter. Can you answer the question?

Comment: @BillAlsept  Your title says "diffract" there Bill.  I think people are probably down-voting it because of the thing Emilio mentions about disparate concepts.

Comment: Your right but I meant diverting trajectories. So how does a photon divert its trajectory behind an edge and why is that question a desperate idea?

Comment: It's not a desperate idea. "Disparate" is a different word to "desperate".

Comment: @PM2Ring Thanks, yes I saw that. Sometimes Siri doesn’t cooperate so well. I still don’t believe these ideas are disparate.

Comment: Dear Bill Alsept, I got the answer I think to your question. In short, the different media have different atomic and molecular structure, a different lattice. The spacing between the lattice's atoms is like the spacing between the slits in the double slit experiment. If you use different wavelength photons for the double slit experiment, you will get different spacings between the interference patterns. This is because the different wavelength photons will (as waves) interfere with itself differently.

Comment: As the different wavelength photons create different spacing between the interference patterns, because of the constructive and destructive interference, the darker areas will be the destructive and the brighter the constructive interferences. Now in different materials, the spacing between atoms is different so you will see different wavelength photons interact with itself (as a wave) in different angles. The only constructive interference will be the angle of refraction. The other angles will be all destructive. This is why in different materials the angle will be different.

Comment: The spacing between the slits in the double slit experiment determines the spacing between the interference pattern and the wavelength of the photons will determine the spacing between the patterns too. Now in different media, the spacing between the atoms is different so the spacing between the patterns will be different and the constructive patterns will be at different angles. Because the angle of refraction will be determined by the constructive interferences, and those depend on the spacing between the atoms.

Comment: The phenomenon I describe is photon diffraction and happens at the edges of matter. As in the two edges of a slit or possibly the edges of atoms on the surface of glass. You can derive the patterns of a slit experiments or refraction through a piece of glass the same way. It can be done with billions of individual photons. Waves are not needed. I derive it at billalsept.com “Single Edge Certainty”

Answer (score 3):

Photons are inherently relativistic and can only be properly described using quantum field theory. However in situations where photon number is not changing we can describe them using [a single photon wavefunction](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/437/what-equation-describes-the-wavefunction-of-a-single-photon) in the same way as we describe any particle in non-relativistic quantum mechanics.

When we do this we just get a plane wave as described by Maxwell's equations. So the wavefunction for a (delocalised) photon propagating through some medium is just the same plane wave that we get from classical electrodynamics. The refraction at a boundary is due to the requirement that this wavefunction be continuous across the boundary.

There is a certain amount of fudging in this argument. We take the group velocity of the wave to be:

$$ v = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\epsilon\mu}} $$

as in classical electrodynamics, and it's the change in the permittivity and permeability between the two media that causes the refraction. However the constants disguise a complicated interaction between the photon and the electrons in the media. Strictly speaking the photon and the media become entangled due to the interaction and we have to consider a global wavefunction covering both. In cases where the interaction is strong this gives us a quasiparticle called a [polariton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polariton). However in most cases the interaction is weak and the photon wavefunction remains well described by a plane wave with the interaction rolled up into the relative permittivity and relative permeability.

Comment: I don’t believe enough emphasis is given to the particle aspect of a photon but could you please explain the  last sentence of your first paragraph I still don’t see what causes the photon do divert left or right or how much. The photon is only big enough to interact with one or two atoms on the boundary.

Comment: @BillAlsept in a light ray the photons are delocalised over (typically) a large distance. So it is incorrect to think of the photon as a little ball of a size comparable to atomic scales. A single photon will simultaneously interact with large numbers of atoms. That's why we can average out the details of the interaction into a change in the permittivity and permeability.

Comment: @BillAlsept re the particle aspect of photons: see [Do photons truly exist in a physical sense or are they just a useful concept like $\sqrt{-1}$?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/303132/do-photons-truly-exist-in-a-physical-sense-or-are-they-just-a-useful-concept-lik).

Comment: but wouldn’t it be much simpler and mathematically derived without fudging if the photons interacted with the boundary in the same way as they do with stars gravity?

Comment: @BillAlsept: no, the propagation of photons in a curved spacetime is a completely different and unrelated phenomenon.

Comment: I realize that but what if it was the same? Who is to say a photon traveling within a close proximity of an atom wouldn’t act the same way as one passing close to a star? With this model you can explain all the phenomenon without fudging.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79779/discussion-between-john-rennie-and-bill-alsept).

Comment: Thanks John, i appreciate that. If you leave a comment I will respond tomorrow. My daughter just called and I need to go pick her up unfortunately. Thanks again

Comment: It does not have to be a plane wave.

Answer (score 1):

Another view:

Photons build up the classical electromagnetic field with its diffractions and refractions in a complex manner, in a superposition of their wavefunctions so that the classical behavior arises .

Single photons interact quantum mechanically. For a refractive medium there must be transparency, and transparency means that images and colors are retained, more or less, i.e. elastic scatters. This means that  the photon cannot be scattering with the  ~ $1^{23}$ molecules of the gas or water or crystal, because the coherency of images will be lost. 
Thus it has to exchange virtual particles with the whole lattice describing the transparent medium it scatters upon, and quantum mechanics gives  a probability of scattering.

[image: compt]

At the surface between two media, the electrons are virtual exchanges , and photon in and out must have the same energy. The mathematical probability if calculated , will give high probability for a single photon to scatter in the direction of the optic ray that zillions of such photons will build up macroscopically. There is continuity in the mathematics between quantum: photon, and classical:light.

In building up the classical wave this probability of scattering in a given direction is high in the direction given by the classical refraction optical ray, and so the classical light built up keeps the image coherence .

See [my answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/188651/shimmering-from-heated-air-and-the-speed-of-light/188690#188690) here on a similar question for links.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79851/discussion-on-answer-by-anna-v-what-causes-a-single-photon-to-diffract).

Answer (score 0):

The bending of the path of a photon passing a star is not due to the photon crossing a boundary.  It is due to gravity, and the gravitational field is continuously distributed in the space surrounding the star. The photon does not need to pass close to the star for its path to be bent; it's just that the amount of bending is too small to measure unless the photon passes relatively close to the star.  Note that most gravitational lensing events have involved galaxy *clusters*, on the order of a hundred million light years across.

Similarly, the wavefunction of a photon is continuously distributed over a very large area, even though it is only *detected* by its interaction with a single atom or molecule. For example, light from a laser might spread over an angle of, say, 0.01 degree. At the range of a hundred light years, the beam has spread to over nearly 0.2 light years wide: nearly 200 million times wider than the Sun. In a coherent laser,the wavefunction of *each photon in the beam* is spread out over the full width of the beam. Because they are not emitted coherently over a large aperture like the photons in a laser beam, wavefunctions of photons from distant stars or galaxies are spread out over much wider angles than the photons in a laser beam.

The bottom line: The effect of gravity on photons as they pass a star can be understood without recourse to quantum mechanics.

Answer (score -2):

Of course John Rennie and Anna V are correct, but it seems that neither is answering your question, how does a photon get around the edge of two mediums in an angle.

Now what you think is that one photon will scatter off one atom the same way as a herd of photons (the EM wave) scatters off a herd of atoms (the medium).

One single photon will scatter off one single atom in a straight line.

You think that the photon just scatters and follows in a straight line, that is not true. The probability distribution of the photon is described by its wavefunction, and the photon gets scattered in every direction. Why do we see it then follow a straight line after scattering? Because that has the highest probability in the wavefunction. Nothing else is acting on the photon, only the atom it scatters off.

It does not have to do anything with gravity that the photons go in an angle at the edge of two media.

The single photon can be scattered off in any direction at the edge of two media, it might get reflected or refracted. What will decide? The atomic and molecular structure of the new medium, and the wavefunction.

So for a single photon, it might not follow the same angle as a herd of photons. Why? Because a herd of photons will scatter differently then a single photon.

A herd of photons will scatter off a herd of atoms differently. Why? Because you do not consider the effects scattered photons have on each other.

What happens when a herd of photons gets scattered off a herd of atoms is that the photons get scattered in every direction, described by the wavefunction. Now the photons scattering will have an effect of the other photons, and some directions will cancel out.

This canceling out will cause the photons to be scattered in only one direction. This is the least probable direction that is canceled out.

In case of a mirror, it is the opposite, in case of glass it is the same as the original direction.

The photons get scattered not only at the edge of two media, like air and glass, but they get scattered as they move through glass, they get scattered on the layers of atoms.

Your question is on the angle at the edge. The edge has a big difference between the two medias density and atomic and molecular structure, that is why the angle is big.

Why is light traveling in a straight line?

It only travels in a straight line in vacuum (and no gravitational field).

Light does not travel in a straight line in a dense medium like glass, only if the density of the glass is the same.

There are parts in glass where density is different and light will not travel in a straight line there. For the same reason why it travels in an angle at the edge of two media, that have different density.

Now why does light change its path when the density changes, and the atomic and molecular structure changes?

It is because when the herd of photons get scattered off a herd of atoms, the photons cancel out each other in some directions.

Now what directions they cancel out depends on the atomic and molecular structure of the media.

When light travels from air to glass, the atomic and molecular structure of glass will make photons get scattered off in one direction (for most of the photons). This angle will be different from the direction light traveled in air, because the atomic and molecular structure of air made light scatter in another direction.

It is because the atomic and molecular structure of air makes photons cancel each other out in a different angle then glass makes them.

The two different media are not in a covalent bond. Their atoms and molecules are not arranged together to make light go in the same direction, and photons to get scattered in the same direction.

That is what you see when light travels from air to glass, that the air atoms and molecules are not in a covalent bond with glass, and they can move separately, they are arranged in a separate direction that will make the photons get scattered in a different angle. The directions that cancel out will be different, because the atoms and molecules of air and glass are not in a covalent bond and are not arranged in the same direction.

[image]

But the difference between the angle between air and glass is not random. When light enters glass from air, it will have the same angle as when it exits. But you can see that the thicker the glass, the more it will shift the image, You can see that by removing glass from its frame and at the edge of the glass you will see the image is shifted compared to the image coming in air.

The change in angle is not only at the edge of two different media, but any two media that is not in a covalent bond.

Answer (score -4):

> What causes a photon to divert its trajectory as it passes a sharp edge or the boundary of two mediums?

The trajectories of photons behind sharp edges are distributed into a swelling intensity. Even photons, emitted one after another, will be distributed in the interaction with sharp (thin) edges in the same manner as a ray of photons.

[John Rennie](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/415193/46708) pointed out, that the interaction between the photon and electrons on the edge could be described as a global wave function (bolded from me):

> > So the wavefunction for a (delocalised) photon propagating through some medium is just the same plane wave that we get from classical electrodynamics. The refraction at a boundary is due to the requirement that this wavefunction be continuous across the boundary... However the constants disguise a complicated interaction between the photon and the electrons in the media. **Strictly speaking the photon and the media become entangled due to the interaction and we have to consider a global wavefunction covering both.** In cases where the interaction is strong this gives us a quasiparticle called a polariton.

As well as a crystal bend X-rays into spots of intensity, the interaction between the photons electric field and magnetic field components and the surface electrons field components has to be a quantized interaction due to the resulting intensity distribution (fringes) on the observation screen.

Comment: Hi Holger, hows it going? You still didn’t answer the question. You used words like “distributed” and “bend” to describe diverting. No one has physically described how a photon goes behind a sharp edge. Or what makes it divert.

Comment: Bill, to make it unambiguous, I added to the photons interaction the more precise “the photons electric field and magnetic field components” ...

Comment: OK so how exactly do the electric and magnetic fields interact to make the photon go left or right? What physically happens? I’m especially asking about a sharp edge.

Comment: In the crystallography it is common sense that the arrangement of the atoms in the lattice is responsible for the refraction and intensity distribution of X-rays. The same holds for visible light and the surface electrons on sharp edges. It is well known that on sharp (or thin) edges the potential difference to the rest of the material is high, means, the concentration of electrons is higher on edges. And the interaction between these electrons and photons is quantized like for a standing wave between to plates.

Comment: OK describe your last sentence in more detail. Like how does the photon physically interact and change direction.

Comment: In [bifringency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birefringence) a crystal with two differente lattice lengths Davide a light beam into two polarized sub-beams. In the case of an edge the photon interacts with the field of the surface electrons, which in these interactions became a quantized field with a swelling electric field structure. An external electric potential as well as an external magnetic field have to affect the spacing of the intensity distribution (fringes).

Comment: How does the photon interact with the field and what is the field or what is the field made of? Does the field pull the photon toward it? If so how? Is the photon deflected into the electron? If so how? Does the photon bounce or scatter off of something? In the case of an edge probably not.