# Pair production form high energy cosmic microwave background photons and related calculations

Tags: quantum-field-theory, cosmic-microwave-background, pair-production

If assume that fluctuating fermion-antifermions pairs in space are products of photon-photon fusion reactions. Thus their total electric charge and total color are null. And the pairs spins are antiparallel and they are on their mass shell. The only quantity which is not conserved is therefore the energy and this is the reason for their limited lifetimes. And suppose that first order properties can be deduced assuming that pairs are created with an average energy, not taking into account full probability density of the pair’s kinetic energy.

Then the energy of an ephemeral fermion/antifermion $ E $ is,

$ E=φm_0 c^2 $

Whereas $ φ $ is the constant of proportionality. And it’s value can be deduced if we know the energy spectrum of the photons with their probabilities to create fermion pairs.

Now, can the high energy-cosmic microwave background photons create fermions as explained above? And if they can how can i calculate the value of $ φ $?

I forgot how to calculate the value of $ φ $ and i'm curious to know whether high energy-cosmic microwave backgound photons can produce fermion-antifermion pairs.

Comment: Where did you find this formula? Do you have are reference?

Comment: No, sorry @my2cts i studied these things long time ago.

Comment: [There are no fluctuating fermion-antifermion pairs in space](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/146003/are-vacuum-fluctuations-really-happening-all-the-time)

Comment: No i assumed that they are products of photon-photon fusion reactions as explained, but not a direct stem of the Heisenberg energy-time relation as you may thought John Rennie

Comment: What high energy-cosmic microwave background photons are you talking about? Microwave photons are far too cold for significant photon-photon interaction, and if you want pair production you need gamma photons, *far* hotter than the CMB has ever been.

Comment: okay i was thinking of this problem too, but do you know how to calculate the value of constant i mentioned, if substitute "high energy-cosmic microwave backgound photons" with gamma photons as you explained? PM 2Ring

Comment: Sorry, I don't. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pair-instability_supernova has some info about pair production in large star cores hotter than $3\times 10^8$K, but no formulae. Of course, pair production is a lot easier in the vicinity of matter than in free space. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-photon_physics says that photon–photon scattering limits the spectrum of observed gammas to a photon energy below 80 TeV, due to the gammas scattering off CMB photons, but it has no formulae either.

Comment: BTW, when replying to comments you should use the `@UserName` syntax so that the person you're replying to gets notified. You automatically get notified about our comments because it's your question.

Comment: Computing *thresholds* is easy (first Mandelstam variable, right?), but getting *rates and spectra* is considerable harder.

Comment: thank you all guys