# Magnetization of vacuum fluctuation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, vacuum, magnetic-moment

In a simplified model one can assume that a vacuum fluctuation creates an electron-positron pair (i.e. positronium) for a short time. Let's assume a photon interacts with this vacuum fluctuation.

Is it possible, that the average magnetic moment $m$ of the positronium in the magnetic field of the photon is non-zero? Is it possible to determine the value?

(That the average polarization is non-zero is quite clear to me.)

Comment: [Are vacuum fluctuations really happening all the time?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/146003/are-vacuum-fluctuations-really-happening-all-the-time)

Comment: That's why I just consider the model that the vacuum fluctuation is a positronium. I could reformulate the question whether the average magnetic moment of positronium is non-zero in a magnetic field but I wanted to emphasize where the question arised.

Comment: Have a look at section 6.2 of Peskin and Schroeder.

Comment: $\mu=g \cdot e/2m \cdot \hat{S}$. But shouldn't the average spin of a vacuum fluctuation positronium vanish. Or is it possible that somehow the photon which creates the magnetic field can conserve the angular momentum and make the average non-zero?